# How to got difference between 2 date in Years ,Month , Days is sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to got difference between 2 date in Years ,Month , Days for

Example :
Hirring Date : 25/7/1998
CurrentDate : 30/9/2017

The resulte to be like :  19 Years – 2 Month – 11 Days

Comment: Why 11 days with your sample dates?

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a Table-Valued Function.  This approach is very precise and performant.  You'll never have to worry about the various date calculations.

**Example or [dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c57b64d7c79b37fc824b8e720f5ff92c)**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, hiredate date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'1998-7-25')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed](A.HireDate,GetDate()) B
```

**Returns (You can ignore or omit Hours, Minutes, and Seconds)**

```
ID  Years   Months  Days    Hours   Minutes Seconds
1   19      2       8       15      21      47
```

The UDF if Interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] (@D1 DateTime,@D2 DateTime)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cteBN(N)   as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cteRN(R)   as (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 From cteBN a,cteBN b,cteBN c),
         cteYY(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(YY,R,@D1))From cteRN R Where DateAdd(YY,R,@D1)<=@D2),
         cteMM(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MM,R,D))  From (Select Top 12 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteYY P Where DateAdd(MM,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteDD(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(DD,R,D))  From (Select Top 31 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMM P Where DateAdd(DD,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteHH(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(HH,R,D))  From (Select Top 24 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteDD P Where DateAdd(HH,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteMI(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MI,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteHH P Where DateAdd(MI,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteSS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(SS,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMI P Where DateAdd(SS,R,D)<=@D2)

    Select [Years]   = cteYY.N
          ,[Months]  = cteMM.N
          ,[Days]    = cteDD.N
          ,[Hours]   = cteHH.N
          ,[Minutes] = cteMI.N
          ,[Seconds] = cteSS.N
          --,[Elapsed] = Format(cteYY.N,'0000')+':'+Format(cteMM.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteDD.N,'00')+' '+Format(cteHH.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteMI.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteSS.N,'00')
     From  cteYY,cteMM,cteDD,cteHH,cteMI,cteSS
)
--Max 1000 years
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('1991-09-12 21:00:00.000',GetDate())
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('2017-01-01 20:30:15','2018-02-05 22:58:35')
```